# How to use carrierwave/minimagick composite to put my logo on the southeast corner of every image uploaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, composite, minimagick

I have a model that allows users to upload pictures using carrierwave. I want to put my logo in the southeast corner of each image and then I want the image to save just as it would normally, (example.com/images/1). I know that I have to use composite but despite several hours of googling I am nowhere closer. This was my best guess.

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]
  process :logo

def logo
  manipulate! do |img|
    logo = ::MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails Name}/app/assets/images/logo.png")
    img = img.composite(logo, Magick::SouthEastGravity, 15, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just change this line

```
process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]
```

to this

```
process resize_to_limit: [400, 400, 'SouthEast']
```

And then you may or may not need some of that extra minimagick code you were adding about gravity.

Answer (score 1):

```
process :watermark   

def watermark
  second_image = MiniMagick::Image.open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/....logo.png")

  manipulate! do |img|
    img.composite(second_image) do |c|
      c.compose "Over"    # OverCompositeOp
      c.gravity "Southeast" # copy second_image onto first_image from (20, 20)
    end
  end
end
```

Got this to work.